# Changing State names to Abbreviations

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list with a mix of state names and abbreviations, that I want to change all to abbreviations.  I know I can use Vlookup (=VLOOKUP(AD12,$J$2:$K$63,2,0)) and a list of state names/abbreviations to change names...but if the cell is already populated with an abbreviation, it returns #N/A.  I wanted to combine an IF statement and LEN(AD12)=2 but getting errors.  Any advice would be appreciated...can I combine LEN and Vlookup in an If/then/else statement?

TIA

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1814374/edit) your post, add a sample of your data and expected results.

Comment: Presuming that the VLOOKUP is written correctly for your data, I would expect that `=IF(LEN(AD12)=2,AD12,VLOOKUP(AD12,$J$2:$K$63,2,0))` would work just fine. As another comment mentions, posting what your data looks like and what results you want will help us confirm.

Comment: Two other options to handling `#N/A` results are `IFNA()` or `XLOOKUP`